# How Do I Get _PublishedWebsites Folder via "AsConfigured" Build Definition Setting?

Tags: msbuild

I'm currently setting up my builds in TFS to output on my build machine "AsConfigured".  However, when I do this, _PublishedWebsites does not show up.  I Get a _PublishedWebsites folder when I set up the build as SingleFolder, but I want to maintain my folder structure.

I've tried setting up a Publishing Profile, but I don't want it to apply to the entire solution (I am specifying the solution to build in the build definition).  Using the following below, I've got close, but it only outputs one of my two web projects:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder;PackageTempRootDir="C:\Publish";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing a Publish Profile with FileSystem in tandem with modifying each web project's csproj file and inserting:

```
<DeployOnBuild Condition=" '$(IsInTFS)' == 'true'">true</DeployOnBuild>
<PublishProfile Condition=" '$(IsInTFS)' == 'true'">MyTFSProfile</PublishProfile>
```

Credit goes to http://dobrish.blogspot.ca/2013/04/web-deployement-in-tfs2012.html